# Object color smooth transition from one color to another

Tags: css, reactjs, colors

I have a component:

```
const Square = styled.div`
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
`;
```

how do i change the color of the square from green to blue gradually (smooth transition from green to blue, maybe over a second)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using reactjs instrumentation... but assuming you are working in a browser environment, you may employ pure CSS animation for that.

Allow me to leave a ready to run example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    .square {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .change-color-to-red {
        animation-name: change-color-to-red;
    }


    @keyframes change-color-to-red {
        0% {  }
        100% { background-color: red}
    }

  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="square change-color-to-red"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[online example](https://jsfiddle.net/kbn6so5e/)